# Android- Add a search view in fragment tab

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, searchview

Hi guys I'm new in android so please help me, 
I want to build an application android which have 2 fragment tabs :

1. Home
2. Search

The second fragment should contain 2 more fragments, 1 for searching & 1 for result.

I create a fragment (Search) which contain a simple search view (which I define only in the xml layout)

This is my code :

**Main Activity :**

```
public class MDASA extends AppCompatActivity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mdasa);
        // add tabs here
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
          // ...
    }
}
```

**Fragment (searching) :**

```
public class FreeOpinion extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
        return v;
    }

}
```

**Fragment.xml :**

```
<SearchView
    android:id="@+id/simpleSearchView"
    style="@style/testSearch"
    android:queryHint="Search here"/>
```

I get the search view but it doesn't do any thing. How can I create a second fragment that contain the result of the searching ?

This is the result of my code:
[a screenshot of my app-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJpkc.png)

*PS :*

I found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41468281/how-to-add-search-view-on-action-bar-on-one-of-the-fragments-in-tab-layout-dynam) that is similar to mine, but as a result I get a second search view in the ActionBar
[a screenshot of my app-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKfJ4.png)

There is also this [code](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html) which seems very useful but I don't know where should i put it (because i have to put the search view in the fragment)

Thanx a lot :)

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't do any thing"? Why do you do to test this? What happens?

Comment: Code-Apprentice 
Yes, I test it , I can write on it but for now I can't search with it because i define the search view only in the xml layout.
This is the first time I work with fragments so I don't now what should i do ,  beside I searched a lot & I didn't found any code or tutorial useful

Comment: @Code-Apprentice ,I found this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230893/android-search-with-fragments/10479208#10479208) but i don't know how to use it because in the main activity i have 2 fragments